# beamer, metroplois, and references

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I'm having trouble adding references in beamer with metropolis theme.  Using just the default theme is fine, but if I switch the theme to metropolis I get added a horizontal line and the word "References", which I don't want because it's already on a frame named "References".

Here's a MWE (no problem here)

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout,english]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib2.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}

@article{einstein,
    author = {Einstein, A.},
    title = {Die Grundlage der allgemeinen Relativitätstheorie},
    journal = {Annalen der Physik},
    volume = {354},
    number = {7},
    doi = {10.1002/andp.19163540702},
    pages = {769--822},
    year = {1916}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bib2.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

 \frametitle{Title}
 A reference\footfullcite{knuth}, with refbib an item of the .bib file.

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
%        \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\printbibliography
%        \bibliography{bib2.bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I add

```
\usetheme[numbering=fraction,titleformat=smallcaps]{metropolis}
```

Now I get the extra horizontal line and "References".
I search metropolis code for anything related to "bib" or references but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do a

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}
```

Maybe the default theme sets this option globally.

Comment: Thank you! I would have never found this.  Grepping beamer source and metropolis source I still have no clue how this gets set.  But this fixed my issue.

Comment: Well, disabling the heading is an option of `biblatex`. And as I said, I am more surprised, that this does not show up in the default, too, than that it actually does in metropolis.